# How to replace special regex chars in Python?

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I need to match the following pattern:

```
text1.cps.text2
text1.text2.cps.text3
cps.text1
```

where text1, text2 are some random words. cps is one of several possible words. So I wrote the following regexp:

```
pattern = "(\w+\.)*?({0})(\w+\.)*"
```

And than I iterate over list of possible words:

```
for word in ['cps.','cps.tbl.']:
   p = pattern.format(word)
```

So the problem is that item from the possible words can contain special regex chars. So I am looking for function that replaces each special character into something like that:

```
cps\. and cps\.tbl\.
```

Comment: Have you tried raw strings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [re](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module defines an `escape` function which does just that. Something like:

```
for word in words:
    pattern = re.escape(word)
    ...
```